# FlexMouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN_OUTSIDE works only for pop-up component?

Tags: apache-flex, events, mouseevent

I have a component that extends UIComponent of Flex, I want to add it a FlexMouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN_OUTSIDE listener but it does not works. that means I can not capture the event. But when I use PopUpManager to add this component, and then add a FlexMouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN_OUTSIDE listener, it works fine.

Is FlexMouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN_OUTSIDE only works for pop-up components?

Thanks for helping

Comment: Well, it is for a feature that allows to close component clicking outside of that component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That event only fires through popups. If you want to check a mouse event you need to add the regular mouse down to the parent container and check if the target is **NOT** the child.

Another way you can do this is by catching the event on the stage and on the component... Since bubbling goes upwards, the component click gets caught first.

```
public var bCompClicked=false;

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onStageClick);
myComponent.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onComponentClick);

private function onComponentClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
     bCompClicked = true;
}

private function onStageClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
     if(!bCompClicked){   //we didn't click the component, so we clicked outside it..
       clickedOutSide();
     }else{
        bCompClicked=false; //we did click the component, set to false for the next time.
     }
}

private function clickedOutSide():void{
    //do what you want when someone clicks outside...
}
```

**Disclaimer** I haven't tested this or thought about it very hard... so it may not work.

Comment: This is a good solution, however, instead of having 2 event listeners, you could just check to see if `event.target == this` in the stage click handler.

Comment: @J_A_X This could become complicated if the component is composited by child controls. So I think the original approach is better.

Comment: @splash Right, you can listen to `event.currentTarget == this` which would return the component that the event listener is attached to and would be called even if it's a child of said component.

Answer (score 0):

This is a follow up on the answer from Jonathan, with a single handler, and taking care of child components if any.

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onStageClick, false, 0, true);

private function onStageClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
  var object:Object = event.target;
  while (object && object != this && object.hasOwnProperty("parent")) {
    object = object.parent;
  }
  if (object != this) {
    // the click is not from this component or its children
  }
}
```